# How to connect Chromecast to WiFi that needs certificate?

Tags: chromecast

Is there any way to import certificates for WiFi networks to Chromecast?

Answer (score 1):

According to a Google employee in a [Chromecast support forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromecast/IY1Fw8Iy3Vk), the Chromecast does not support 802.1X.